# Get quarter's begin/end dates

Tags: ruby, date

How would I calculate a date's [quarter begin/end dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_year)? If example if I give the method `"2012-10-11"` I would like back: `{ :begin_date => '2012-10-01', :end_date => '2012-12-31' }`

```
def quarter_dates(date = Date.today)
  # TODO...
  return {
    :begin_date => begin_date,
    :end_date => end_date
  }
end
```

Comment: Here are the quarters that I am referring to - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) provides [`beginning_of_quarter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_quarter) and [`end_of_quarter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-end_of_quarter) for just this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'

def quarter_dates(date = Date.today)
  {
    begin_date: date.beginning_of_quarter,
    end_date: date.end_of_quarter
  }
end
```

Comment: You might show the poster how to use just the date extensions needed, instead of all of ActiveSupport's core extensions.

Comment: Yes, I should have do that. @AndrewMarshall thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work :

```
def quarter_dates(date = Date.today)
  start_month = date.month - (date.month - 1) % 3
  start_date  = Date.new(date.year, start_month, 1)

  {
    :begin_date => start_date,
    :end_date   => (start_date >> 3) - 1
  }
end
```

To help you understand, see this bit :

```
(1..12).map { |month| month - (month - 1) % 3 }
#=> [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10]
```

The operator `>>` on a date will return the date `n` months later and the `- 1` will return the date one day before.

Comment: `(month - 1) / 3 + 1` would be simpler and more intuitive.

Comment: It's not the same, this will give 1, 2, 3 and 4 for each quarter while the one in the answer returns 1, 4, 7 and 10 for each quarter. So you directly get the start month.

Comment: Sorry. I should have written `(month - 1) / 3 * 3 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

### Reference:

Using quarter date ranges provided here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_year

> 1. First quarter: from the beginning of January to the end of March
> 2. Second quarter: from the beginning of April to the end of June
> 3. Third quarter: from the beginning of July to the end of September
> 4. Fourth quarter: from the beginning of October to the end of December

### [Date](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) & [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) Syntax:

An simple solution would use some logic like this:

```
# Is today's date in Q4?

(Date.parse('2012-10-01')..Date.parse('2012-12-31')).cover?(Date.today)
```

### Solution:

Following this logic:

```
def quarter_dates(date = Date.today)

  4.times do |i|
    start = Date.parse("#{date.year}-#{i*3+1}-01")
    if (start..(start >> 3 - 1)).cover?(date)
      return {
        :begin_date => start,
        :end_date => (start >> 3) - 1
      }
    end
  end

end
```

A bit dirty in places, but I figure it should give you a head start.